# How do I get an onscreen keyboard with Swipe and contextual prediction on windows 7? I have a pen tablet as an input

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, on-screen-keyboard

I have a pen tablet that serves as a brilliant input - I don't use a mouse anymore.

I want to use a swipe + contextual predictor on screen keyboard for my computer. Is there any software available for windows 8 that i can install on windows 7?

ALSO, if all is vain, should I take the pain of installing an android emulator? Will it hog any memory?